# Settings returns nil for all configurations which reads from environment variables in devise.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, passenger

I am using `config` gem for configuration management in Rails 4.2.5 application. I am facing a strange issue where it looks like config loads after `devise.rb` and so not able to find any config from `settings.yml` in production reading some environment variables.

Here is `application.rb` config

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)
require 'rails/all'
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Magnificent
  class Application < Rails::Application
    Config::Integration::Rails::Railtie.preload
  end
end
```

**devise.rb**

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.omniauth :twitter, Settings.twitter.consumer_key, Settings.twitter.consumer_secret, strategy_class: OmniAuth::Strategies::Twitter
  config.omniauth :facebook, Settings.facebook.app_id, Settings.facebook.app_secret , { info_fields: 'email,first_name,last_name' , scope: 'email,public_profile' }
end
```

**settings.yml**

```
twitter:
  consumer_key: <%= ENV['TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY'] %>
  consumer_secret: <%= ENV['TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET'] %>
facebook:
  app_id: <%= ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_ID'] %>
  app_secret: <%= ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET'] %>
```

P.S. This works perfectly in development environment. Also, When I access `Settings.twitter.consumer_key` from the console in production, it shows the value.

The application runs on Passenger 5.0.25.

**EDIT**
Few models also use settings from config that read values from environment variables. Such settings also have nil values. Surprisingly all those settings reading values from environment have properly value set when I check from console(`RAILS_ENV=production rails c`)

Comment: What do you mean by `config.rb`?

Comment: Well this might be trivial but the docs say you should add `Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)` before `Config::Integration::Rails::Railtie.preload`, did you try that?

Comment: Yes. That is already there.

Comment: Someone is facing same issue with Unicorn and figaro gem as well. https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro/issues/210

Comment: I got bitten by setting environment variables in the shell, but then finding out that my command was actually issuing a command to a daemon running in another process tree, so it didn't see the environment I was setting. One solution was to set the environment variables sooner, like in .bashrc, to force it to be visible in all processes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a yml file with key as environment variable name. Then added environment variables before module declaration in application.rb

```
require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

if Rails.env.production?
  config_file = '/srv/shared_filesystem/pdf-config.yml'
  if File.exists?(config_file)
    config = YAML.load(File.read(config_file))
    config.each do |key, value|
      ENV[key] ||= value.to_s unless value.kind_of? Hash
    end
  else
    raise 'Missing required configuration file /srv/shared_filesystem_ro/pdf-config.yml'
  end
end

module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
  .. ..
  .. ..
  end
end
```